# Counting number of label in MIT-BIH arrhythmia Database (MIT-BIH)

Tags: machine-learning

According to this paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/293174514_Deep_Learning_Approach_for_Active_Classification_of_Electrocardiogram_Signals 
the number of beats of types N,S,F,V is as follow
[image]

For the training test for MIT-BIH (DS1), they use these records {101, 106, 108, 109, 112, 114, 115, 116, 118, 119, 122, 124, 201, 203, 205,
207, 208, 209, 215, 220, 223, 230}.

However, when I check using https://physionet.org/cgi-bin/atm/ATM and choose **Describe record** in the **toolbox**, the number are not matching. Only record number 208 have 2 S label (while it's total 973 in DS1 according to the paper). Also the total number of N label is not matching (40589 instead of 45777). While F and V labels are ok.

Here's the meaning for the label: https://physionet.org/physiobank/annotations.shtml 
I need only N,S,F,V beats.

Can anyone tell me what's the problem or where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in a PDF. This is the way the 15 Labels are combined into N V S F and Q.

[image]